# Express area of a regular tube of radius $r$ around a curve $\pmb{\alpha}$

Tags: differential-geometry

I need to show that the area of a regular tube of radius $r$ around a curve $\pmb{\alpha}$ is $2\pi r$ times the arc length of $\pmb{\alpha}$. The parametrization of the tube is that $$\pmb{x}(s,v) = \pmb{\alpha}(s) + r(\pmb{n}(s)\cos(v) + \pmb{b}(s)\sin(v))$$, where $\pmb{n}(s)$ is the unit normal vector and $\pmb{b}(s)$ is the binormal vector. I have that $\pmb{x}_{s} = \pmb{\alpha}'(s) + r(\pmb{n}'(s)\cos{v} + \pmb{b}'(s)+\sin{v})$ and $\pmb{x}_{v} = r(-\pmb{n}(s)\sin{v}+\pmb{b}(s)\cos{v})$. Then $\pmb{x}_{s} \times \pmb{x}_{v} = -r(1-rk(s)\cos{v})(\pmb{n}(s)\cos{v}+\pmb{b}(s)\sin{v})$. Then $|\pmb{x}_{s} \times \pmb{x}_{v}| = r(1-rk(s)\cos{v})$. Then according to the definition, the area \begin{align}
A &= \iint_{U} r(1-rk(s)\cos{v})dsdv\\
&= \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{l} r(1-rk(s)\cos{v})dsdv
\end{align} where $l$ is the arc length of $\pmb{\alpha}$. But I don't know how to go from here to prove the final statement. Could anyone help me please? Thanks!

Comment: You certainly mean a *closed* curve? Why aren't your $v$ limits $0$ to $2\pi$? Check your cross product computation, also, as the area integral is incorrect.